# errors compiling a program that uses the WordNet library in C

Tags: c, wordnet

I have successfully installed WordNet library. Now I am trying to use the library in a program, but I cannot get a sample program to build. I get linker errors (undefined reference) even though the library search path is correct.

Here is the error:

```
gcc -g -I/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/include  -o wordnet_sample.o -c wordnet_sample.c
gcc -L/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/lib -lWN -o wordnet_sample wordnet_sample.o
wordnet_sample.o: In function `main':
/home/user/wordnet_sample/wordnet_sample.c:6: undefined reference to `wninit'
```

This is the Makefile

```
WORDNET_INSTALL=/usr/local/WordNet-3.0
CFLAGS=-g -I$(WORDNET_INSTALL)/include
LDFLAGS=-L$(WORDNET_INSTALL)/lib -lWN

wordnet_sample: wordnet_sample.o
        gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o wordnet_sample wordnet_sample.o

wordnet_sample.o: wordnet_sample.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o wordnet_sample.o -c wordnet_sample.c
```

This is the sample program

```
#include <wn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int isOpen = 0 == wninit();
    if (isOpen) {
            printf("wordnet opened!\n");
    }
    else {
            printf("Could not open WordNet dictionary!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The WordNet library is installed

```
[user@local wordnet_sample]$ ls -l /usr/local/WordNet-3.0/lib/
total 180
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 172344 May  3 15:34 libWN.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 May  3 15:34 wnres
```

I suspect that I may need more arguments to the linker, but I am really not sure. Does anyone come across this? Does anyone know why the undefined reference error is happening even though I have the right library and library search path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-c` to `CFLAGS`.

Also the first `gcc` command needs to have the libraries after the objects. You may put LDFLAGS in the end:

```
gcc -o wordnet_sample wordnet_sample.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

Better yet, have separate `LDFLAGS` (linker *options*) and `LIBS` (actual libraries to link). So:

```
LDFLAGS=-L$(WORDNET_INSTALL)/lib
LIBS=-lWN
....
gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o wordnet_sample wordnet_sample.o $(LIBS)
```

Comment: I have updated the makefile but it still did not work. Could I trouble you to explain to me as to why -c is needed?

Comment: What does not work exactly? `-c` means "compile only, do not link". Your makefile structure is designed for compiling and linking in two separate phases. Doing it in one phase, as suggested in the other answer, is only good for small projects with one or two source files.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I changed the Makefile CFLAGS line to this: CFLAGS=-g -c -I$(WORDNET_INSTALL)/include   and removed it from the wordnet_sample.o target (left everything else as is).  I still ended up with the same error (undefined refence to wninit).  I guess I will have to dome some reading of the gcc man page.

Comment: I see the other problem now. The library (-lWN) needs to be specified *after* the object in the link command, so you need to move `LDFLAGS` around.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! This was exactly my problem; I needed to list the libraries after the object file.